# Clicking the button of the recyclerview item makes buttons of other recyclerview item respond too

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a recyclerview usin cardview and added  button in each of the items of the recyclerview. I have already integrated the button click event . Now, when I click the button of one of the recyclerview item it responds normally and the button of other items responds too at the same time as if they are also clicked.what is the problem? how can it be solved?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="95dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_vendor1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_direction" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vendorName1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_vendor1"
            android:text="Kozzaja Infotech Pvt Ltd"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            style="@style/RatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vendorName1"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_vendor1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vendorName1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="38dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_call_black_36dp" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="38dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_messenger_outline_black_36dp" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="38dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_black_24dp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/layout"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
                android:tag="off"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="11dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is my adapter's code.

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(workers.get(position).getName());
    holder.rating.setRating(workers.get(position).getRatings());
    Picasso.with(context).load(workers.get(position).getImageLogo()).fit().into(holder.imageView);
    holder.plus.setTag("off");


    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /// button click event
            if (holder.plus.getTag().toString().equals("off")) {
                holder.plus.setTag("on");
                holder.plus.setText("-");
                //show the options button using animation
                holder.layout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.left_to_right));
                holder.layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else if (holder.plus.getTag().toString().equals("on")) {
                holder.plus.setTag("off");
                holder.plus.setText("+");
                //hide the options button using animation
                holder.layout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.right_to_left));
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //disappear the button after 500ms
                        holder.layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How do you know that button of other items responds too at the same time? What have you observed? Is holder.layout getting invisible/gone for others also?